# Segmentation Error from unix ksh script

Tags: unix, ksh

I am facing a SIGSEGV Error when running a ksh script in a new unix server where IBM Infosphere version 8 has been just installed.
I am getting the error when a unix script updates the extraction date time in Configuration file. The script is called by a Datastage sequence.

The script aborts with the issue :
"Program "/bin/sh" terminated. [SIGSEGV] segmentation violation".

A web search for the issue says the issue is caused by invalid reference to memory.

Below mentioned is the command to execute the script.

```
"ksh shUpdate_Config.sh MEARS MSDS_MP_ATTRIBUTES_BS_VW /data/projects/scver_etl/EXTRACTS_pub/configurationfiles/MEARS.MSDS_MP_ATTRIBUTES_BS_VW.Lastupdseqno.dat /data/projects/scver_etl/EXTRACTS_pub/configurationfiles/ '2012-08-08 12:35:24'"
```

Here is the content of the script -

```
    #!/bin/ksh
    #########################################################################
    #Script Name:-shUpdate_Config.sh
    #
    #Script Description:- The script updates the STATUS_TABLE with the Extraction Date time and updates the sequence number by 1.
    #
    #Created By:- Vineet
    #
    #Job History:-
    #
    #Sl No          Version           Modification Date         Modified by                Modification Desc
    #01.            Initial               11/04/2012                   Vineet                    Initial Version
        #########################################################################################################################################

if [ $# -ne 5 ]
then
    print "Incorrect number of parameters passed, Quiting ..."
    exit 1
fi
# Enter the Source Id From the user
srcid=$1
# Enter the source table name by user
tabnme=$2
# Enter the Status File Name from User
filename=$3
#Enter the Temp file Path from User
file_path=$4
#Enter the Server time to be updated
Server_datetime=$5
if [ ! -f $filename ]
then
    print "Configuration File not present at the required path, Quiting ..."
    exit 1
fi

grep $srcid $filename >> /dev/null

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then

    print "Source system name not found in configuration file, Quiting ..."
    exit 1
fi

grep $tabnme $filename >> /dev/null

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then

    print "Source view name not found in configuration file, Quiting ..."
    exit 1
fi

while [ 1 ]
do
    if [ -f $filename.lock ]
   then
            sleep 60
    else
            break
    fi
done
touch $filename.lock

DT=`echo $Server_datetime|cut -c1-10`
TM=`echo $Server_datetime|cut -c12-19`


awk '{FS="|";OFS="|"};{a=$3;b=$4;if ($1=="'$srcid'"&& $2=="'$tabnme'") {$3=a+1;$4="'$DT'"" ""'$TM'"} else{}{print $0}}' $filename > $file_path$srcid.$tabnme.tmp

if [ $? -ne 0 ]

then
    print "Process failed, Quiting ..."
    /bin/rm $filename.lock
    exit 1
fi

#fi
mv  $file_path$srcid.$tabnme.tmp $filename

if [ $? -ne 0 ]

then
    print "Process failed, Quiting ..."
    /bin/rm $filename.lock
    exit 1
fi

/bin/rm $filename.lock

if [ $? -ne 0 ]

then
    print "Process failed, Quiting ..."
    exit 1    
fi
exit 0
```

Here is the contents of the file(MEARS MSDS_MP_EVENTS_BS_VW Lastupdseqno) we are trying to update -

```
Source_sys_name|Source_tbl_name|Seq_No|Extraction_date|Extraction_Mode
MEARS|MSDS_MP_EVENTS_BS_VW|37|2012-08-08 11:51:19|D
```

Kindly help!

Comment: Does it really say "/bin/sh terminated" when you're running /bin/ksh? Where is it dying (what does `ksh -x script ....` show as the last few lines)?

Answer (score 0):

> The script is called by a Datastage sequence.
> The script aborts with the issue:
>
> ```
> "Program "/bin/sh" terminated. [SIGSEGV] segmentation violation".
> ```

From the above, I understand that the script is called from a different program
as defined by your invocation string: `"ksh shUpdate_Config.sh ... "`

The way this works is that any external command (what you call a *Datastage sequence*) that you define gets executed by a unix `system(string)` library call.  This in turn invokes:

```
/bin/sh -c <string>
```

Apparently, something is wrong with that invocation, as it is not `ksh` that crashes, but `/bin/sh`.

The first thing to check would be the commandline `"ksh shUpdate_Config.sh ..."`  For starters, does your definition actually *include* the double quotes `"`, or did you add those for this example?